# Keep content blocks up-to-date Not working?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dynamic, content

I have an email that uses a dynamic content block which switches images based on country.

When I selected the option "Choose Keep content blocks up-to-date to apply future source block edits to emails using the block.", it doesnt seem to work?

I created an email dropped in that content, then changed the image in the dynamic content block to something different but it does not seem to apply to the current email?

Answer (score 2):

If these emails are used in Triggered Sends or Journey Builder (being Triggered Sends in their underlying infrastructure), that for any code changes to be propagated, you have to individually republish each trigger. In Journey Builder it requires you to revisit and update each email send activity, which you need updated.

This caching is actually a safety feature, in addition to a speed enhancement. By caching, it prevents untested changes from immediately being sent by the journey.